# Angularjs files uploads says this request has no response data available

Tags: angularjs, ng-file-upload

I used the code below to upload Image and username to server. it works fine.

Now I want to return the username and filename in a console but it says  **this request has no response data available**. I have tried to use a `successcallback()` function but still with no luck. it seems the issue is from the `successcallback()`. can someone help me fix that.

```
        file.upload = Upload.upload({
      method: 'post',
          url: 'image.php',
         data: {username: $scope.username, file: file},


        }).then(function successCallback(response) {

    alert(response.data[0].username);
    alert(response.data[0].file);
    console.log(response.data[0].username);
    });
```

**below is the entire code**

```
    //inject angular file upload directives and services.
    var app = angular.module('fileUpload', ['ngFileUpload']);

    app.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', 'Upload', '$timeout','$http', function ($scope, Upload, $timeout, $http) {
        $scope.uploadPic = function(file) {
        file.upload = Upload.upload({
          url: 'upload.php',
          data: {username: $scope.username, file: file},
        });

        file.upload.then(function (response) {
          $timeout(function () {
            file.result = response.data;
console.log(response.data[0].username);
          });
        }, function (response) {
          if (response.status > 0)
            $scope.errorMsg = response.status + ': ' + response.data;
        }, function (evt) {
          // Math.min is to fix IE which reports 200% sometimes
          file.progress = Math.min(100, parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total));
        });
        }
    }]);
```

**image.php**

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
 $username = strip_tags($data->username);


$return_arr[] = array("username"=>$username);
 echo json_encode($return_arr);
exit();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue mentioned in the post above has been resolved.

I was sending the form parameter username as `json_decode()`

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
 $username = strip_tags($data->username);
```

Sending everything as post parameter solved my problem as in case below

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
```

Thanks